# How to find siRNA off-targets from RNA-seq data?

Tags: rna-seq

I have an `RNA-seq` dataset from `siRNAs` targeting different components of a molecular pathway. the problem is that the **siRNA target gene is less down-regulated from several other genes**.

*I'd like to know which genes are down-regulated due to the off-target effect of the siRNA and which ones are down-regulated because of the down-regulation of my target gene.*

So, how can I find the **off-targets** of my siRNA considering having the RNA-seq data and also the siRNA sequence?

If there is no package in R, Python, or shell. Could you please introduce me to an online tool for finding potential off-targets using my siRNA sequence. That way I can search for off-targets and then exclude them from my DGE list manually.

Comment: I do not think that the target must be the most downregulated one. siRNA is not knockout, just knockdown. In my experiments where I knockdown certain transcription factors many target genes of that TF are often completely silenced as a consequence while the fold changes of the TF itself are more modest. Same can be the case here. Maybe your gene co-regulates others. I think you should consider biology first. Maybe download large consortium data like GTEx and run sth. like WGCNA to see whether your gene is in a coexpression network with these genes you talk about.

Comment: The problem gets even worse when considering that two of the siRNA targets aren't even differentially down-regulated to be part of any co-expression network!!

Comment: about co-expression modules, what if the off-target is also in the co-expression module, how can say if the gene is an off-target or is down-regulated because of my target knockdown?

Comment: In the end you typically use several siRNAs for the same gene and then check which genes are consistently downregulated. This tells you whether some genes are due to off-targets or the RNAi itself.

Comment: Nice idea @ATpoint . I don't have several siRNAs targeting same gene. But I have several siRNAs targeting different genes which their proteins aggregate to a complex! So, I guess I can somehow use this idea. I mean just check the DEGs in a heatmap and see which ones are constantly down in most of the treatment. What do you think?